# Integer nonlinear optimization with a fixed domain

Tags: python, r, optimization

Here is the original table:

```
       Column1   Column2
Row1    4 (x1)    6(x3)
Row2    5 (x2)    4(x4)
```

`x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4` mean the new values after swapping

Originally the variance of each column is:

```
Var(column1)= var(c(4,5))=0.5
Var(column2)= var(c(6,4))=2
```

After swapping the values lesser than 10 in the original table, the new variances of two columns respectively are:

```
New_Var(column1)=(x1-(x1+x2)/2)^2+(x2-(x1+x2)/2)^2
New_Var(column2)=(x3-(x3+x4)/2)^2+(x4-(x3+x4)/2)^2
```

My objective is to

```
Minimize  | New_Var(column1) – 0.5 | + | New_Var(column2) – 2 |
```

Here the notation ‘| |’ means absolute.

The constrains are that `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4` can only get a value respectively from a fixed domain, here say `{4, 5, 4, 6}`. And all the four variables need be swapped to a different value, say that `x1` cannot be 4, `x3` cannot be 6 so on so forth.

Note that all values in the original table here are larger than 10 because I just want to make the question look like simple.

In realistic, the table is `6000*10` which is very large. So outputting all the unique permutations and testing  is not a suitable method.

I have read the `task view of optimization` in R. There are a lot of optimization packages there. So I need more specific guidance.

Below is the function that can swap values lesser than 10 to a different values lesser than 10 respectively. Hope it helps.

```
derangement <- function(x){
  if(max(table(x)) > length(x)/2) return(NA)
  while(TRUE){
    y <- sample(x)
    if(all(y != x)) return(y)
  }
}

swapFun <- function(x, n = 10){
  inx <- which(x < n)
  y <- derangement(x[inx])
  if(length(y) == 1) return(NA) 
  x[inx] <- y
  x
}

set.seed(10)
swapFun(c(1,2,3,10,4,11,2,12))
#[1]  2  4 10  2 11  1 12
```

How can I solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: I do not understand why this question is regarded as too broad. It is surely just a optimization problem. Could you tell me what is wrong with this question?

Comment: I edit it again in another question.

Answer (score 0):

For problems this size you can easily use brute force.

In R:

```
library(combinat)
pp <- permn(c(1,2,2,3)) ## construct list of permutations
pp <- unique(pp)        ## unique permutations only
```

Apply your (new) constraint "x1 cannot be 1, x2 cannot be 2, x3 cannot be 2, x4 cannot be 3":

```
ok <- function(X) {
   !(X[1]==1 | X[2]==2 | X[3]==2 | X[4]==3)
}
pp <- pp[sapply(pp,ok)]
```

There are `length(pp)` == 2 non-identical, valid combinations (you can test whether `length(pp)>0` to see if there are any valid combinations left).

```
## define objective function
f <- function(X) { (X[1]-X[2])^2 + (X[1]-X[3])^2+ 
        (X[2]-X[3]-X[4])^2+X[4]^2+X[3]^2 }
## compute obj function for all permutations
vals <- sapply(pp,f)
## identify minima
pp[which(vals==min(vals))]
## [[1]]
## [1] 2 3 1 2
```

This will break down as the domain grows and the size of (n!) gets large ... at which point you may need to start doing research in the domain of *integer programming* (e.g. see the [Optimization Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/view=Optimization))

In Python you would first generate the list of permutations with `itertools.permutations` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)) and then use a comprehension to apply the objective function across the iterator.

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot. I forget to add another condition, say variables x1 cannot be 1,  x2 cannot be 2, x3 cannot be 2, x4 cannot be 3. I know sometimes there will no feasible solution. so first I will use another function to test whether there is a feasible solution. Then I will use the optimization package to get the optimal solution.

Comment: by the way, I hope this isn't homework ... I probably should have asked for more context, and more evidence of effort on your part, before answering ...

Comment: Thanks. It is definitely not my homework. Actually I have written this kind of funtion to deal with the problem. But when the length of the domain becomes very large., this approach need a lot computing time......So I come here to ask whether there are some good solvers in R can tackle with this problem quickly. I am not familiar with this kind of packages.

Comment: OK: in your question should try to give a better sense of a realistic context: how big are the problems you are trying to solve? And what have you already done? Otherwise, people (like me) will waste time repeating what you've done ... As a start, try following the "task view" link in my answer. Also, you're supposed to frame problems as "how do I solve?" and not "is there a package" (even if "use package XX" turns out to be the answer ...)

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot. I also know the 'task view' in the previous time. There are really a lot packages there, I gave up reading it  in the previous time because I think my problem is very special and it is difficulty for me to find the suitable package. So I come here to ask some more specific guidances....... But now I will read the 'task view' carefully....

Comment: Yes. I see. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I write this sometimes as a set of linear assignment constraints:

```
 sum(i, δ[i,j]) = 1  forall j
 sum(j, δ[i,j]) = 1  forall i
 x[i] = sum(j, δ[i,j] * v[j])
 δ[i,j] ∈ {0,1}     (binary variables)
 v = [1, 2, 2, 3]   (constants)  
 i,j ∈ {1..4}       (indices}
```

Here δ is a binary variable that performs like a permutation matrix.

Comment: Could you please show me which optimization package you use for this problem?

Comment: There is no good support for general MINLP models in R I believe. If the model was linear OMPR is interesting. If the model is quadratic, Cplex or Gurobi are good candidates.

Comment: Thanks. I will tell you the result later.

Comment: I have reedited this question. I think it is not a MINLP model but a integer nonlinear model.  Could you please give me some specific guidance of how to write the code of this example in R?

Comment: I still need `x1` !=1, `x2`!=2, `x3`!=2, `x4'!=3. It seems the set of constraints cannot indicate this. ....

Comment: This is so trivial. E.g. `x1 != 1` means `δ[1,1]=0`.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Could you please send me the link that show the similar problem solved by the written R codes. The example  will be very helpfully because I have no experience of written this kind of code. Many thanks.